# How to get a static IP adress with 4G simcard on a Formuler Z11 Pro IPTV set-top-box?

Tags: internet

I hope someone can assist me. I frequently travel between countries in my van. The issue i'm facing is that I enjoy watching television, so I recently purchased the latest IPTV set-top box: https://pandoraiptv.com/product/formuler-z11-pro-max/. The box and everything else are functioning perfectly however my subscription only functions with a Dutch IP address. How can I obtain a static Dutch IP address?

Comment: Having a question about networking or rocket science while on the road does not make the question travel.se material. I am voting to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

Sign up for a VPN service that has end-points in the Netherlands. Set your device to use the VPN connection and specify the end-point you want.

Your IP address will, most likely, be static (that of the VPN provider), and it will be Dutch to comply with the geofencing requiements. Plus, it provides a level of security, privacy and anonymity for your browsing & TV watching (whether you want/need that or not, it's nice to not be tracked *too* closely).

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! So if I understand correctly, I need to install a VPN application on my 4G device or on the IPTV box?

Comment: If you can install a VPN app on the IPTV box, that would do the trick. Otherwise, you'll need a router that has built in VPN support (most modern ones probably will). That, however, is a question for a different Stack.

Comment: Also note that some providers don't quite like IP addresses that come from ranges more likely to be servers than end-users (precisely because they are usually VPN endpoints, and they may have licensing issues, or issues with advertising when they get revenue from that) and block things based on that. YMMV a lot depending on the provider, and over time. Do not be surprised if it doesn't work, or if one day it just stops working.

Comment: That's a good point, @jcaron!

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks for the suggestion! I'm planning to try it out with Nord VPN. Do you have any other VPN service recommendations or do you think Nord VPN is a good choice? I'll be traveling to the UK next week, so it's the perfect opportunity to test it out!

By the way, just to clarify, I don't watch TV while I'm driving. I only do that when I've parked my van.

Comment: Product recommendations are, generally, off-topic.